# ColdFusion: Best way to use HTMLEditFormat for all form input fields

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfml

I have form uses `HTMLEditFormat` call for every single input fields.  is there any way so I can call `HTMLEditFormat` function only once and it will take care of all input fields instead of adding it to every single field?

Comment: `HTMLEditFormat` has no concept of "input fields". (That is all client side) The function simply encodes a single string. It is possible there are other options, or ways to structure your code, but we need to see the code first ...

Comment: FYI if u use cfinput, they're all HTMLEditFormat'ed.  Or, you can loop through the data structure and HTMLEditFormat'ed them before you output them between ##

Comment: In addition to the other comments, be aware that `HTMLEditFormat` only protects variables in the HTML body. You need to do more for variables in HTML attributes, JavaScript, CSS and URLs.  See this - [Is HTMLEditFormat enough?](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2010/8/26/Is-HTMLEditFormat-enough)

Comment: @Henry, how's that again about cfinput and htmleditformat?

Comment: @DanBracuk `<cfinput name="bar" value="foo">` === `<input id="bar" name="bar" value="#htmlEditFormat('foo')#">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will accomplish your goal, but like has been pointed out in the comments section, this may not be your best option.

```
<cfset cleanForm = {}>
<cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="i">
  <cfset cleanForm[i] = HTMLEditFormat(form[i])>
</cfloop>
```

Instead of referencing `form.firstName` you would now reference `cleanForm.firstName`

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to apply the `HTMLEditFormat()` function against each form value separately.  But if you're currently writing out a line of code for each form field to do that:

```
cleanFormData.firstName= HTMLEditFormat(form.firstName)
cleanFormData.lastName= HTMLEditFormat(form.lastName)
```

You can revise your code to take advantage of the fact that all of those form values are in the form scope - which is essentially a ColdFusion struct variable - and you can write code that loops through the struct and applies `HTMLEditFormat()` against the form value in the current iteration.